# Spotify - delete access token created with None value

Tags: python, spotipy

I am trying to delete my Spotify access token generated with a None value, which broke at my second connection attempt.

I got this snippet from here --> [github thread](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/176#issuecomment-307632735), used to clear the cached token:

```
import os
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

scope = <whatever_youwant>
try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
except (AttributeError, JSONDecodeError):
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
```

but I get syntax error here:

```
os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
```

where is my token cached? how can I delete it as to regain access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache should be stored in a file at the root directory (where the python file gets executed).

It's named `.cache-{username}`. Make sure that you have hidden files turned on or else you probably won't see it.